# Change Javascript array to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array in JavaScript

```
("error", "No name entered", "Invalid Email", "No Message")
```

The array can also be

```
("success", "Your message has been sent.")
```

I would like to create a string that looks like this

```
<div class="error">
<ul>
    <li>No Name entered</li>
    <li>Invalid Email</li>
    <li>No Message</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The first item in the array is used for the div class the rest will be list items,

i've tried using formData[0], formData[1], etc. but that just prints undefined if the array item doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the variable called housing the original array?

Comment: The array is called formData

Comment: You could dynamically create an unordered list , `append` the array elements while running it through a loop till the array length

Comment: Why don't use some templating engine like https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski I guess it is easier to use something like handlebars in this case.

Comment: @vittore Handlebars is great too, or underscore templates if you're already using underscore and don't wan't extra dependencies,pick your poison.Just don't create the html by hand its error prone and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
var array = ["error", "No name entered", "Invalid Email", "No Message"];

function makeDiv(array) {
var newDiv = '<div class="' + array[0] + '"><ul>';

for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        newDiv += '<li>' + array[i] + '</li>';
}

newDiv += '</ul></div>';

//append newDiv somewhere

}
```

Comment: Why would you loop through all items? Always take the first item and make it a div. Then loop from `1` to `length`. The `if`/`else` is unnecessary to include in the loop

Comment: @Ian -- Made the changes, makes much more sense...I was over thinking the first element with useless logic :\

Comment: @tymeJV No problem. It was perfectly valid before, I just thought it was a little unnecessary when it's always the first item you're checking for. If it were like every other item, it would obviously need to be included

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
var formData = ["error", "No name entered", "Invalid Email", "No Message"];

for (var i = 0, len = formData.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        var wrapper = $('<div />', { 'class' : formData[i] }).appendTo('body');
        $('<ul />').appendTo(wrapper);
    }
    else {
        $('<li />', { text : formData[i] }).appendTo('div.' + formData[0] + ' > ul');
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jSQeL/).

As pointed out in the comments, though, it'd be easier to avoid re-querying the DOM each iteration, so this version maintains references to the various created-elements:

```
var formData = ["error", "No name entered", "Invalid Email", "No Message"];

for (var i = 0, len = formData.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        var wrapper = $('<div />', { 'class' : formData[i] }).appendTo('body'),
            ul = $('<ul />').appendTo(wrapper);
    }
    else {
        $('<li />', { text : formData[i] }).appendTo(ul);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jSQeL/1/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [Creating HTML elements with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

Comment: Why aren't you storing references to the elements that you create (the `ul`) and appending the `li` elements to that, instead of querying the DOM **every loop iteration**?

Comment: @Ian: because, honestly, I thought about doing that when I wrote the original (posted that to provide a useful answer) and then got distracted by dinner. *blush...*

Comment: @DavidThomas Haha just trying to help :) Good answer, by the way!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
$('div').addClass(formData[0]);
$('li').each(function(index, el){ $(el).html(formData[index] || '') });
```

According comments is better to use a for loop, http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/73:

```
var lis = $('li');
for( int i = 0; i < lis.size(); i ++ ){
  var li = lis.eq(i);
  li.html(formData[i] || '');
}
```

Comment: uhg... jQuery `.each()` is insanely slow!

Comment: what to use instead? a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = ["error", "No name entered", "Invalid Email", "No Message"]
  , first = formData.shift()
  , elem = $('<div />').addClass(first)
  , ul = $('<ul />').appendTo(elem)

 $.each(formData, function( ind, item ) {
    $('<li />').text(item).appendTo(ul)
 })

 // now elem has your DOM element
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you post the variable names for your arrays? This may be due to a reference error / assignment error.

In the mean time, a simple for loop could do the trick, but you may also want to look into JavaScript [templating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript_templating). It can make things like this much more simple.

Here's a JS Fiddle that may help you:
http://jsfiddle.net/HepFw/

```
var failureMessage = ["error", "No name entered", "Invalid Email", "No Message"],
    successMessage = ["success", "Your message has been sent."];


function getMarkup ( resultArray ) {
    var markup = "";

    for ( var i = 0, loopCount = resultArray.length; i < loopCount; i++) {
        if ( i === 0 ) {
            markup += '<div class="' + resultArray[i] + '"><ul>';
        }
        else {
            markup += '<li>' + resultArray[i] + '</li>';
        }    
    }

    return markup += '</ul></div>';   
}

document.getElementById('so-example-success').innerHTML = getMarkup( successMessage );
document.getElementById('so-example-failure').innerHTML = getMarkup( failureMessage );
```